# Apache Pig: filter based on tupple member content

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm learning Apache Pig and have encountered an issue to realise what I wish. 
I've this object (after doing a GROUP BY):

```
MLSET_1: {group chararray,MLSET: {(key: chararray, text: chararray)}}
```

I'd like to GENERATE key only when a certain pattern (PATTERN_A) appears in text AND another pattern (PATTERN_B) does not appear in the text field for one key.

I know that I can use MLSET.text to get a tupple of all text values for a specific key but then I'm still having the same issue on how to filter on the list of items from a tuple.

Here's an example:

```
(key_A,{(key_A,start),(key_A,stop),(key_A,unknown),(key_A,whatever)})
(key_B,{(key_B,stop),(key_B,whatever)})
(key_C,{(key_C,start),(key_C,stop),(key_C,whatever)})
```

I'd like to get keys for lines where "start" appears and "unknown" does not appears. In this example I will get only key_C as a result.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code that might help you out. The solution is a nested foreach here:

```
C = FOREACH MLSET_1 {F1 = FILTER MLSET BY (text == PATTERN_A); F2 = FILTER MLSET BY (text != PATTERN_B); GENERATE group, COUNT(F1) AS cnt1, COUNT(F2) AS cnt2;};
D = FILTER C BY (cnt1 > 1 AND cnt2 == 0);
```

you'll probably have to adapt the comparison in the nested filter.

Comment: Fred,i suppose to post the same solution but you posted 2 mins before. Timing is very important. +1.

Comment: Hi @Fred and thank you for your quick answer. I think we are close to the solution here but you misunderstood part of the question (which may not be clear enough). I'm editing the question to add an example which will make the question more clear.

Comment: the procedure is pretty much the same but i'll edit the answer

Comment: Hi again @Fred. Thanks for clarifying this, now I fully understand the logic behind this and was able to get what I wanted. I did modify a little what you suggested: I test if PATTERN_B is here and then I filter on cnt2==0. Here's the final command line: C = FOREACH MLSET_1 {F1 = FILTER MLSET BY (text == PATTERN_A); F2 = FILTER MLSET BY (text == PATTERN_B); GENERATE group, COUNT(F1) AS cnt1, COUNT(F2) AS cnt2;};
D = FILTER C BY (cnt1 >= 1 AND cnt2 == 0);

Answer (score 0):

Here the another approach

```
C = FOREACH MLSET_1 GENERATE $0,$1,BagToString(MLSET.(key,text));
D = FILTER C BY ($2 MATCHES '.*start.*') AND NOT($2 MATCHES '.*unknown.*');
E = FOREACH D GENERATE $0,$1;
DUMP E;
```

**Output for the above input:**

```
(key_c,{(key_c,start),(key_c,stop),(key_c,whatever)})
```